# The tallest building I have ever seen was in New York. Is the use of 'was' acceptable here?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

A student has written

> The tallest building I have ever seen **was** in New York.

I know the expected formation is

> The tallest building I have ever seen **is** in New York.

But is the first sentence grammatically acceptable too?

There are other sentences like:

> The hottest place I have ever been to was Florida.
>
> The longest journey I have ever taken was when I went to Los Angeles.

Comment: It's just "backshifting" (making the tense of auxiliary verb ***was*** agree with the "past" sense of preceding Present Perfect ***have** [ever] **seen, been, taken,...***), which is perfectly natural in many contexts, ***not just reported speech***. When you say you "know the expected formation is...", you mean that's what ***you mistakenly*** expected. Native speakers don't think or expect anything like that.

Comment: Your examples using _was_ seem perfectly idiomatic to me. I know the building in New York is presumably still there, but the moment when the speaker had that thought about it is in the past.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think closing this question as a duplicate of that one would be quite sad, given that the only answer to that question currently has a score of -1.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Well, I'm not convinced that's a good reason not to cite it. If someone has a *better* answer, better they post it to the earlier question, not here. Whatever - I've put a bounty on the cited dup. And I do take your point - particularly given that if a cited dup has no upvotes for the question AND any answers, the system won't allow it to be used for a dup vct. So if I remember in future, if no ***answer*** in the cited dup has any upvotes, I'll do the same as I've just done here. I've offered a bounty on the "neglected" earlier question, which may improve things soon.